# Twitterizer - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitterizer

I have noticed a problem with Twitterizer in that it's has been working fine until my client added a tweet to her account containing an image powered by Photobucket.

Then we started getting the Object reference error above. It's taken a an hour or two to determine that it was actually the tweet causing the issue which I've now removed however how can I get round this problem?

My code is below which is a very basic solution for pulling the time line in:

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.AccessToken = AccessToken;
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = AccessTokenSecret;
tokens.ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey;
tokens.ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret;

try
{
  UserTimelineOptions opts = new UserTimelineOptions();
  opts.IncludeRetweets = false;
  opts.UseSSL = true;
  opts.Count = 5;

  /* Throws Exception -> */ TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> timeLine =  TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(tokens, opts);
  uxTweets.DataSource = timeLine.ResponseObject;
  uxTweets.DataBind();
}
catch
{
  uxError.Text = "<p class=\"p1\">Twitter isn't configured correctly. Twitter is not responding.</p>";
}
```

**Updated Stack Trace for Brian:**

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Twitterizer.Entities.Converter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) +1355
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueProperty(JsonReader reader, JsonProperty property, Object target, Boolean gottenCurrentValue, Object currentValue) +165
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonReader reader, Object target) +476
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) +702
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) +110
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) +867
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) +92
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) +495
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateAndPopulateList>b__0(IList l, Boolean isTemporaryListReference) +98
   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionUtils.CreateAndPopulateList(Type listType, Action`2 populateList) +554
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateList(JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) +103
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String reference) +61
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) +119
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract) +130
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +94
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +47
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +105
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +74
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value) +42
   Twitterizer.Core.SerializationHelper`1.Deserialize(Byte[] webResponseData, DeserializationHandler deserializationHandler) +91
   Twitterizer.Core.TwitterCommand`1.ExecuteCommand() +2867
   Twitterizer.TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(OAuthTokens tokens, UserTimelineOptions options) +48
   DataComuniqueUtils.Twitter.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Paul Stoker\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DataComuniqueUtils\DataComuniqueUtils\Twitter.ascx.cs:41
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace from the exception.

Comment: the error usually means something is being assigned to a null object. can you be specific which line of the code triggers this?

Comment: Thanks Bahamut, I've edited the post to show where the exception is thrown. I don't think the Twitterizer.Entities library has been updated to handle images unless I'm totally missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: This one just nailed me today on a site that has been working fine for the past year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been having this problem. Downgrading Newtonsoft.json.dll to 4.3.* fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new bug in the Twitterizer library. I haven't had the chance to determine the cause, but it appears to be some change in the structure of data returned by the Twitter API in some situations (I believe it's related to entity data).

Or, and this is a worse scenario: it's a new bug in the JSON.NET library, which is used by Twitterizer to automatically read json data into objects.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Ricky, I'll keep an eye on the github repo for updates ;-)